# VSTS Bug Count Per User Story

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, testing, tfs, project-management

We am looking to get a list of bugs per user story in TFS so we can identify the areas that caused the most pain.

Anyone have any ideas of the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance,

B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you track User Stories?  I'm guessing these are work items.
You could add a custom field to the Bug work Item that can be used to contain the Work Item Id that represents the User Story, then write a report or custom query to extract the data.  This obviously requires those reporting the bugs to be aware of the user stories.

Alternatively you could link the bug to the user story and use a defined comment value to identify the user story as the source of the bug.  This would require a custom report to extract the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the quality  of user story by linking the bugs and test cases to user story. Link the bugs using "Related" link. Also link the test case (if any ) using "Tested by" link. You can use the AL reporting services to see the story over view status with these link. it will show the testing status, open  bugs status related to the US. All tasks can be linked as child items of the user story.
See below link for more information, Thanks

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380648.aspx